# One or more participants failed to draw(): error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-visualization

I have a google pie chart with dashboard. When the dropdown category Picker has no value, in other word when there is no value to display in the pie, i get "One or more participants failed to draw()×".

I even see the same error happening for below example When there is no data to display for the Pie chart.

jsfiddle.net/asgallant/rEhUp/

Any idea on this?

Comment: If there is no data, you can't draw a chart.  What would you like to have happen?

Comment: I want to see the page only with message 'No data'. I dont want user to see the "One or more participants failed to draw()×" message.  
But i found the solution, I added 

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'error', function (err) {

     google.visualization.errors.removeError(err.id);
     
});   
After this Line

var chart = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')). bind([categoryPicker], [table,pie]);   . Thanks Asgallant For your quick response.